# Reviewing suggested edits - what is an invalid, incorrect or radical edit

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

Reviewing suggested edits I find several that seem to add some useful facts to an answer. Should I reject these as invalid or incorrect or radical edits? I am not asking which of the reasons to choose. I want some guidance on what changes should be accepted.

Examples:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3946262 adds information for other browser types.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3946315 describes how to handle an additional set of results.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3946389 adds a line to

All of the above have been rejected. I skipped them to see what happened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of them should be rejected.  They are all adding/changing the *content* of the post, the intended *meaning* of the author.  That is not appropriate for an edit.  (Unless the post is Community Wiki.)

The intent of edits is to allow readers to more effectively understand *the authors original intent*.  They are not there to change the author's intent.

If someone wishes to provide entirely separate information they can do so either through a comment (in the hopes that the author decides to incorporate the information into the answer) or if the information is sufficiently valuable, a new answer can be posted that answers the question, but also includes whatever additional information is desired.

Comment: Your words @Servy "The intent of edits is to allow readers to more effectively understand the authors original intent" are very helpful, as is the rest of your answer.