# When auditing edits, what to do with large changes that look OK?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Per the rules, they should be rejected as too large, but sometimes the change (though a very substantial change to the question/answer) really seem to clarify the point.

I such cases I'd want to have an option of "Let the original poster decide," but I'm not clear how that should work out. Run it by OP if that is the winning option? Give OP a shot at editing and queue for reopening?

Comment: I sometimes completely rewrite badly phrased questions.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen, I do so too quite often. But what I mean is not just to fix horrible English, properly indent source code, or rewrite equations in LaTeX. It is cases where the edit adds missing context, gives references to the papers OP hints at, completes half-written programs, adds a complex example.

Comment: Yeah. How comprehensible was [the original question here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/16121/revisions)?

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen, that I'd have accepted without much qualms (it just rewrites what OP says readably).

Comment: See also the answer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218183/reviewing-suggested-edits-what-is-an-invalid-incorrect-or-radical-edit

Comment: @AdrianHHH, thanks. That clarifies the issue quite a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's impossible to say in abstract that some form of editing should be *always* allowed, or *always* rejected. You're expected to use your judgement and do your best to interpret the edits in the context where they appear: **are they helpful in furthering the goals of the post while respecting the intent of the original author?** Don't try to shortcut the process by looking for cheap excuses to reject an edit.

If an edit to a question results in it tackling a completely different problem, or an edit to an answer results in it presenting a completely different solution, you should probably reject these.

But an edit that adds helpful (and plausible, given the original author's own words) context to a question, or fleshes out explanations or examples in an answer... Those *can* be welcome additions. You be the judge.

Remember: if you approve something useful but the original author doesn't like it for some reason, he can always roll it back.